# SQL Query Select based on a condition with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a **Batch** entity and a **Job** entity. A Batch can have many Jobs.

Now, Job has a column called `'status'` with values `'REVIEW', 'NEW', 'EDIT'`, and `'QA'`.

I need to Select all Batches with a value `'YES'` if any job belonging those batches is having the status `'REVIEW'` and with `'NO'` if no job is having the status `'REVIEW'` and the query will be Grouped by Batch.

```
Select Batches.name, Batches.<column_I_need>, Batches.user_id
INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.batch_id = Batches.id
GROUP BY Batches.id;
```

Comment: your question is a bit unclear, could you please add the table structure and sample data

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to check your requirements:

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.name,
    b.user_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN j.status = 'REVIEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO' END AS status
FROM Batches b
INNER JOIN Jobs j
    ON j.batch_id = b.id
GROUP BY
    b.id;
```

Assuming that `Batches.id` be the primary key column of that table, then if we `GROUP BY` that column we may also select any column from the `Batches` table.

Comment: @RajeshOmanakuttan Can you mark this answer correct if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `case exists`:

```
Select b.name, b.user_id,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from jobs j
                          where j.batch_id = b.id and j.status = 'Review'
                         )
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as status
from batches b;
```

This approach is more efficient than an aggregation approach, because it eliminates the `group by`.  With an index on `jobs(batch_id, status)`, this would have optimal performance.